# Preg_replace that allows apostrophes

Tags: php

I'm having trouble making a `preg_replace` allow apostrophes. The current preg_replace won't allow them. What do I need to change to make them possible?

```
$string="I'm an apostrophe";
preg_replace('#<br\s*/?-->#i', "\n", $string)
```

Comment: How does that not allow apostrophes? It doesn't do anything because there's no `<br` in the string.

Comment: Let me check and see if I can clarify my issue.

Comment: What are you trying to do?